# jQuery mobile/cordova weird toolbar layout bug when changing pages

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, layout, toolbar

I'm writing a jQuery mobile app for Android/iOS using Cordova.
I've come across a bug which I've been trying to solve for a few hours and I  just can't figure it out.
When changing pages using jQuery's $.mobile.changePage function, the page's toolbars positions are offset as can be seen in the attached image.
Once I open the keyboard or change the screen orientation it fixes itself.
This bug is not evident on iOS or desktop browsers from what I can tell.

Any help will be appreciated as I'm really pulling my hair out over this..
Thanks alot, Tal

** Please ignore the volume indicator
[image]

Comment: are you using jqm 1.4?

Comment: I'm using jqm 1.3.2. Should I use a newer version?

Comment: no, it's not the issue. I asked you because `mobile.changePage` is deprecated in 1.4. Anyway, this is a common issue for fixed toolbars on Android. Try calling `$.mobile.resetActivePageHeight();` on `pageshow`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to help..

Comment: There must be other solution/workaround but unfortunately, i don't have an Android device to test them.

Comment: Although updating to 1.4 actually solved the original issue, but introduced a few new issues.. It broke my custom theme apart from other smaller issues that arose

Comment: Theme roller supports 1.4RC1 now, you can update it if you wish. But note that there are countless changes in 1.4RC1. If you decide to switch to 1.4RC1, you need to read changes log thoroughly.

Comment: Eventually I updated jqm to version 1.4RC1 and fixed all of the little quirks that came up. It is now working properly.
Thanks